# Database can't compare input with its data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to do a little login-page where I can use sqlite3.
Well, if I login with a username and with a password it will always let me pass even if I didn't add them to the database. 
There is the method of the database class which should look after the data of the user, if it's known or unknown. 
Besides I add my little test to look, if the database is really empty.

```
class Database:

    def __init__(self):
        # Connect to file
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(
            r"C:\Users\Anonym\Documents\Data.txt",
            check_same_thread=False)

        # Create Cursor
        self.c = self.connection.cursor()

        # Table already created?
        try:
            self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")

        # Table doesn't exist
        except:
            self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE Users(User VARCHAR(20), Password VARCHAR(100))")        

    def UserInDatabase(self, name: str, password: str) -> bool:
        """
        Is the user already in the database?
        Yes => True
        No => False
        """
        password = hashlib.sha384(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
        password = hashlib.sha384(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()

        # ---------------------------------------------------------
        # !!! Why does it always pass the try - clause? !!!
        try:
            self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = ?;", (name,))
            self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Password = ?", (password, ))
            return True

        except Exception:
            # User is unkown
            return False
        # ---------------------------------------------------------
    (...)
```

My Test:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Database = Database()

    # Database is emtpy
    print(list(Database.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")))

    # Returns "True" although nobody is in the database?
    print(Database.UserInDatabase("Somebody", "GoodPassword"))

    # Exit Database
    Database.close()
```

The output of it is:

```
[]
True
```

I expect the ouput:

```
[]
False
```

because the database is empty but it still returns `True`. 
Why doesn't it occur an error to "activate" the except-clause?

Comment: the table Users exists, the query returns no results but it doesn't raise any error.

Comment: Well but doesn't ```elf.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = ?;", (name,))``` look after the username in the database? I mean it should return occur an error because ```"Somebody"``` isn't in the database yet.

Comment: looking for a value doesnt' raise any error if there is no match. You're just asking the database if someone is called 'somebody', if you check the result with `fetchall()`, the answer *is* no

Comment: Oh! Now I got it, thank you very much for your answers. :)
Is it possible to tick your comment as an answer because and I can't see tick or something else